# How to opening files

Tags: c++, file

I'm having some troubles trying to open a file so can someone explain how this while loop works here:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");
int a,b;
while (file >> a >> b){}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Check the state of `infile` before the while loop. `thefile.txt` probably doesn't reside in your current working directory.

Comment: I can't understand how that while works in this. What does file>>a>>b do

Comment: I love when they say 'some troubles'. Always reminds me of an extract from the plane log book. "Pilot request: something is rattling in the left engine. Technician comment: Something is fixed."

Comment: Make sure to launch the program inside the folder containing the file. For example, visual studio (for reasons unknown) launches the program in the project directory by default. (One of the first things I tend to do these days is change that setting to $(OutDir) when creating a new project)

Comment: I didn;t try running it yet i just want to understand how the while loop works

Comment: @Irene _"What does `file>>a>>b` do"_ It tries to extract numeric inputs from `file` and stores these to `a` and `b` as long the `file` stream is in `good()` state.

Comment: The title of this question is a little misleading.

Comment: @Irene _"I didn;t try running it yet ...."_ So how can you state in your question you've got _trouble with opening the file_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop has an empty body.  Hence, all it will do, is evaluate the expression `file >> a >> b` until it gets false

`file>>a>>b` reads two integer from the file that you've opened. If it encounters an error or an end of file, it will be false.

**Edit:**

But you mention problems when opening the file.  Here you could check if it succeeds, or why it fails:

```
if (!file) 
   cerr<<"Couldn't open the file:"<< strerror(errno) <<endl;  // or alternatively
                                                              // use the good old perror()
else 
   ...
```

Comment: So it sorts the first two numbers it finds into a and b?

Comment: @Irene It doesn't sort, it just reads a series two space separated integers into `a` and `b` until it reaches the end of file or until it encounters an error.

Comment: THe first number it encounters will be in a, the second in b,  then it llops again, so the third number will be in a and the fourth in b, and so on...

Comment: And if it ever finds something that isn't an integer-- "fubar", the .14 in 3.14, a blob of non text information--it stops.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually unclear what you're asking about. How to open the file correctly, or how `while (file >> a >> b)` works when it can't be opened corectly.

Well, trying to explain the code in comments:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt"); // Tries to open the file in the current working 
                                     // directory the program is executed
int a,b;
while (file >> a >> b){} // Will try to read numeric values from file and store them to 
                         // a and b. If the file couldn't be opened, or the parsing 
                         // for numeric values failed, the loop will never be entered or 
                         // immediately end
```